# How can I take file names from a text document, find them in windows explorer, then transfer the specific files to another folder?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, search, autohotkey

I have a .txt with 900+ file names of pictures with full directories (ex: 2017/conference/tsd-60545).

My windows explorer is pulling from an ftp for my company, and has over 160K photos in it.

I only need the 900 images in my .txt file.

Is there a way to automate this? Manual is bringing me to a slow death.

Answer (score 0):

**This downloads all jpgs from ftp:://ftp.mydomain.com/2017/conference/tsd-60545**

Create a file called "commands.ftp" based on the contents of your `txt` file using a tool like vim, awk, or sed. Then use the windows `ftp` command with option `-s` to process it.

**commands.ftp**

```
open ftp.mydomain.com
user myusername mypassword
cd mysubdirectory
prompt
mget 2017/conference/tsd-60545/*.jpg
close
quit
```

**batch file**

```
ftp -s:commands.ftp -n
```

Comment: Thank you, Jim - will this work if each of my directories and files have unique names? here is a sample of the text file:

Conference 2017/CBK/CB-53886.png
Conference 2017/CLSO/1219733001M-L.png
Conference 2017/CR/CR-2035.png
Conference 2017/DL/DL062BAE1Z0.png
...etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested as I do not have an ftp server to test this with now, but this should work.

Create a batch file with a `.cmd` or `.bat` extention, ensure your test file is in the same directory, or specify the full path to it in the batch file.
Basically, you echo the entire connection to a file. Run a for loop to read from your FTP file and do a `get` or `put` for each entry in the file. Once it is completed, it will run the ftp command and read from the file.

**MyFTPscript.cmd**

```
@echo off
echo user username password> ftpto.dat
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do echo get %%A >> ftpto.dat
echo quit>> ftpto.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpto.dat ftp.imagesserver.com
```

You can test it first to make sure it is actually writing the `.dat` file without actually ftp'ing anything adding `rem` before the last command. like this:

```
rem ftp -n -s:ftpto.dat ftp.imagesserver.com
```

Once you are happy that the content of the dat file looks ok, you can remove the `rem` and run the script which will then do everything.

No need to delete the file as it will re-write it each time you run the command file.